# How to implement current-based charge termination for lithium

Tags: battery-charging

Despite much searching, I've been unable to find a good charging solution for my lithium battery project, so am wondering if I'm misunderstanding something.

My application calls for a 4S battery (no BMS...I will monitor voltages myself). The battery will be portable, and for simplicity am imagining it can be bulk charged in series while on the road (ie, no balanced charging, except occasionally).

My focus is therefore on a simple charging circuit for the series cells. It seems that a variety of suitable constant-current/constant-voltage power supplies (buck/boost) are available, so the challenge becomes how to best terminate the charge cycle.

I've looked at a number of charge protection modules (and BMS'), but it appears that they are not typically (at least that I've been able to find) designed to terminate the charge based on current (ie 10%C). The [8254A](https://www.mouser.com/datasheet/2/360/S8254A_E-1365929.pdf), for example, is a popular protection IC used in amazon/ebay products, and it seems to monitor voltage alone.

On the other hand, it seems that there are a huge number of charge controller ICs out there ideal for lithium charging ([Example](https://www.mouser.com/datasheet/2/609/17318fs-1269775.pdf)).

Since there are so many BMSs and protection modules around I have a hard time believing a charging module does not exist. Yet, apart from perhaps a hobby charger (which I can't really integrate into my package) I can't find any at all. I feel like I'm missing something...

In a nutshell: Given a CC/CV power supply, how can I best implement charge termination at 10%C?

Comment: Saying simple charging circuit when choosing lithium sounds like a **bad** idea.

Comment: The BMS and the charger are different and have different purposes. The BMS is not intended to terminate charge or discharge under normal conditions. The charger is supposed to terminate charging. If you use a CC/CV power supply to charge the battery, there is no simple way to terminate at 10% of C (also called C/10). I am sure the internet will go crazy telling you you need to use a BMS. I mostly agree, but that is not what you asked about. The way charging is normally terminated is that the charger monitors current and terminates during CV phase when I = C/10...

Comment: It needn't be C/10. But there is some current threshold where the charger terminates. Also, many chargers also have a timeout for the CV phase so that they do not float the batteries indefinitely at 4.2 V per cell in the event that the current should never decline to C/10.